# How to check if a value of a keys of an array exist in another array?

Tags: python

I can do this:

```
filter(lambda x: x.key1 in ["aa", "bb", "cc"], [{key1: ..., key2: ...}, {key1: ...}])
```

How can I do the opposite thing?

```
dict_items = [{key1: ..., key2: ...}, {key1: ...}]
filter(lambda x: x in ???dict_items.key1???, ["aa", "bb", "cc"])
```

Comment: You cannot access to dictionary items by dot notation. `x.key1` will give you an attribute error. Can you add a sample input and an expected output  to your question? Or show the output of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two `dicts d1 = {key1: val1, key2: val2`} and `d2 = {key3: val3, key4: val4}`

It's not clear what you are trying to compare but if you want to compare keys just type:

```
set.intersection(set(d1.keys()), set(d2.keys()))
```

For values:

```
set.intersection(set(d1.values()), set(d2.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use list comprehension as follows:

```
a = {"aa":1, "ll":4}
b = {"bb": 'pl', "xx":12, "qq": 66}
print [key for j in [a, b] for key, val in j.iteritems() if key in ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]
```

Or if you only require keys u can use:

```
print [key for j in [a, b] for key in j.keys() if key in ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]
```

output:

```
['aa', 'bb']
```